# Selenium Webdriver java with ( . ) getting replaced

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am building an application where i am using selenium, and now i am doing testing.

The program works well but there is a problem with Computers with Hebrew Language installed.

for example on :

```
sendKeys("blabla@gmail.com");
```

the "." gets replaced with a Hebrew letter "ץ" which is the same place of the "." on the keyboard.

Did someone face this problem before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, tbh this is the first time I'm seeing smthn like that, I would strongly recommend to check your system or IDE settings first, also you may try smthn like this:

```
sendKeys(new String("blabla@gmail.com".getBytes(), "UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same and was only resolved when Hebrew keyboard layout was removed. 
See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=2762
I couldn't change mine to Querty as my keyboard is UK and not US